# Is char or varchar better for a database with utf-8 encoding?

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

I am making a table of users where I will store all their info: username, password, etc. My question is: Is it better to store usernames in VARCHAR with a utf-8 encoded table or in CHAR. I am asking because char is only 1 byte and utf-8 encodes up to 3 bytes for some characters and I do not know whether I might lose data. Is it even possible to use CHAR in that case or do I have to use VARCHAR?

Comment: It almost sounds like you do not realize that a `VARCHAR(x)` can store a maximum of `x` *characters* regardless of the byte width of each character -- it is NOT limited to `x` *bytes*... and that a `CHAR(x)` column is not "only 1 byte," it is `x` characters, and much more inefficient on disk.   Also, you should not "store" users' passwords, of course.

Comment: Maybe i am not asking the right thing because of that the utf-8 encode some characters with more than 1 byte some of them are encoded with 3 bytes and I wandering does these 3 bytes are fit in CHAR which is 1 byte or i have to use VARCHAR instead. Please correct me if i mistake.

Comment: The size of both a `CHAR` and a `VARCHAR` is expressed in characters, not bytes.  A `CHAR(1)` can store exactly 1 *character*, whether it is encoded as 1, 2, or 3 bytes.  A `VARCHAR(1)` is subject to the same constraint.  Oversimplifying things a little bit, the most significant difference is that `CHAR` is not as efficient on disk or in memory unless every row's value is exactly the declared length.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the rule is to use `CHAR` encoding under the following circumstances:

- You have short codes that are the same length (think state abbreviations).
- Sometimes when you have short code that might differ in length, but you can count the characters on one hand.
- When powers-that-be say you have to use `CHAR`.
- When you want to demonstrate how padding with spaces at the end of the string causes unexpected behavior.

In other cases, use `VARCHAR()`.  In practice, users of the database don't expect a bunch of spaces at the end of strings.

Comment: A related tip:  Most cases for `CHAR` can/should be `CHARACTER SET ascii` (postal_code, country_code, md5, etc)